# Landsat 8 Cloud Masking using Pixel QA in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, landsat, cloud-cover

I have a scene that has clouds and shadows which I would like to mask before I continue with my Classification. I am using LC08_L1TP_180073_20141224_20170416_01_T1 which has a pixel QA file.

I downloaded the ArcMap Landsat QA toolbox and usedthe tool to decode and Extract QA bands. Now I have the resulting raster with values of 0 and 1.

But how do I use this raster to mask the clouds out of the bands?

[image]

Comment: As per the [Tour] please try to ask only one question per question.

Answer (score 1):

I would make the pixels you want masked = 0 and all other pixels = 1, then use raster calculator and multiply the images.